# Private server for firebase admin

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

My question is if I'm using firebase and I also need to do backend stuff, i.e. send an email to the user, register the user in my database. Then I will also need firebase's admin service account set up to verify the user. Now, can I use my own server to run admin service account or does firebase/Google force me to use Google's app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK can be run on any server that can run the code.

For example, the Admin SDK for Node.js is just a regular node module. This means it can be run on any node environment: your own server, on App Engine Flex/GCE/GKE/etc, or on the serverless [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). All work equally fine.

Comment: So I should be able to run on my local several, i.e. localhost?

Comment: That's an easy way to get started indeed. Try it, and let us know if you have problems.